# EF Core, табличные функции и расширение entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

Есть базовая сущность импорта каких-то данных:

```cs
public class ImportEntity : Entity<int>
{
    public string RequestType { get; set; }

    public string ManageType { get; set; }  
}
```

Есть табличная функция, которая возвращает весь набор этих данных, но так же добавляет туда 2 высчитываемых столбца (`id`, `request_type`, `manage_type`, `last_request`, `request_count`).
Данные получаются так:

```
var entities = await context.Import
                    .FromSqlRaw("select * from fnt_get_unhandled_import_v2(@start, @end, @lastCheck)", start, end, lastCheck)
                    .ToListAsync();

return entities;
```

Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы в `ImportEntity` была информация о двух новых столбцах (`last_request`, `request_count`), но `ImportEntity` нельзя модифицировать, т.к. изначальная таблица не содержит этих столбцов, а `builder.Ignore` будет пропускать (либо есть механизм отключения `Ignore` на каких-то свойствах в нужный момент времени?) их в мапинге через `FromSqlRaw` (если дописать их в `ImportEntity`)?

Важно, чтобы `ImportEntity` попадал в `ChangeTracker` и данные обновлялись в таблице, к которой относится `ImportEntity`

Использую EF Core 7 (.net 7)

Comment: [Tracking and custom projections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking#tracking-and-custom-projections)

Comment: Да, но там Linq, а не табличные функции

Comment: Советую изучить https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframeworkcore/

Comment: Metanit хорош, но если покажите там пункт, который будет решать мою проблему - будет отлично :)